# Why is my data not being transfered to gpu in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a problem with training a SegNet model
Here is my train function:

```
def train(model, optimizer, scheduler, loss_fn, score_fn, epochs, data_tr, data_vl, device):

    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    losses_train = []
    losses_val = []
    scores_train = []
    scores_val = []

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        tic = time()
        print('* Epoch %d/%d' % (epoch+1, epochs))

        avg_loss = 0
        model.train()  # train mode
        for X_batch, Y_batch in data_tr:
            # data to device
            X_batch = X_batch.to(device)
            Y_batch = Y_batch.to(device)            

            # set parameter gradients to zero
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward
            Y_pred = model(X_batch)
            #print("Y_pred len: ", Y_pred.size())
            #print("Y_batch len: ", Y_batch.size())
            loss = loss_fn(Y_pred, Y_batch) # forward-pass

            loss.backward()  # backward-pass
            optimizer.step()  # update weights

            # calculate loss to show the user
            avg_loss += loss / len(data_tr)

        toc = time()
        print('train_loss: %f' % avg_loss)
        losses_train.append(avg_loss)

        # train score
        avg_score_train = score_fn(model, iou_pytorch, data_tr)
        scores_train.append(avg_score_train)

        # val loss
        avg_loss_val = 0
        model.eval()  # testing mode
        for X_val, Y_val in data_vl:
            with torch.no_grad():
                Y_hat = model(X_val.to(device)).detach().cpu()# detach and put into cpu

                loss = loss_fn(Y_hat, Y_val) # forward-pass
                avg_loss_val += loss / len(data_vl)

        toc = time()
        print('val_loss: %f' % avg_loss_val)
        losses_val.append(avg_loss_val)

        # val score
        avg_score_val = score_fn(model, iou_pytorch, data_vl)
        scores_val.append(avg_score_val)

        if scheduler:
            #scheduler.step(avg_score_val)
            scheduler.step()

        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
          
    return (losses_train, losses_val, scores_train, scores_val)
```

it prints train_loss and then an RuntimeError:

> Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type
> (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same or input should be a
> MKLDNN tensor and weight is a dense tensor

What is wrong in my code?

There must be an error with data transfer to CUDA, but it seems I had already transfered all tensors
Also by some reason this error occurs only if I train model on my PC
For example there is no this error in colab

Comment: optimizer = optimizer.to(device), try this once

Comment: you can try using torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = False to turn off the cuDNN optimization to see if that resolves the error

Comment: where does the value for `iou_pytorch` comes from?

Comment: make sure that device variable is gpu, not cpu. From the error, your inputs on cpu. which means device variable is not correctly set

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Y_val` is not on the cuda device during your validation step:

```
for X_val, Y_val in data_vl:
    with torch.no_grad():
        Y_hat = model(X_val.to(device)).detach().cpu() # detach and put into cpu

        loss = loss_fn(Y_hat, Y_val.to(device)) # forward-pass
        avg_loss_val += loss / len(data_vl)
```

Comment: But there is Y_val.to(device) in forward pass
Have I write something else for transfer?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In your code, you are not transferring your data to the cuda device whereas in my provided code, I am.

Comment: Oh, sure, I missed it (by some reason read not Y_val, but X_val)
But anyway it did not solve the problem